# Is it possible to call the class for only Android Module?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have 2 classes named `DateTimePicker` and `CenterLockHorizontalScrollview`. `CenterLockHorizontalScrollview` is the child of `DateTimePicker`. I don't want to access `CenterLockHorizontalScrollview` outside of the module.

Is there a way to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you just need to mark the class `internal` (e.g., `internal class CenterLockHorizontalScrollview`).  See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html for more information on visibility modifiers like `internal`.